# Difference between getting jQuery's $(selector).each() 'element' parameter, vs $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any difference (related to performance or something else) on getting jQuery `.each()`'s `element` parameter

```
$(".element").each(function(i, e){
   console.log("element: " + $(e));
});
```

and using `$(this)`?

```
$(".element").each(function(){
   console.log("element: " + $(this));
});
```

I've done several tests and programatically I didn't noticed any difference. I'm always using `$(this)` because it's the standard used on most applications.

Comment: No, there's no difference, `this` is a special variable that caches the element in this case, and `el` is a regular variable that caches the element, so it's really exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no practical difference.  In the [source of `each`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.each), we can see that the same thing (`obj[i]`) is passed to `call` to be used as both `this` and the 2nd parameter within your callback:

```
value = callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

While there's no practical difference in your example, the availability of `e` within an enclosed function, or method-call, is a useful feature.

For example:

```
$('.element').each(function(i, e) {
    $('.otherElement').text(function(index, element){

      // in this method, $(this) is an element from
      // the $('.otherElement) collection (also $(element));
      // to access elements of the $(`.element') collection
      // we can no longer use $(this), but we can still use
      // $(e) (or e):

      return $(e).eq(index).text(); // will set the text of the $(element)
                          // to the text of the $(e) element
    });
})
```